CameraIndexSwitch to UnlitSurface in Realty Composer Pro
I am trying to create a Material in Reality Composer Pro for a stereoscopic view.
I have two Image inputs connecting to CameraIndexSwitch - but I can't connect the output of CameraIndexSwitch to the UnlitSurface. The error notification is "Cannot connect Float to Color3"
I tried to Image to subtype color3f, but it's disabled.



My mistake - I should have used a "RealityKit" Image

It should be color3f if you disconnect everything and start from the image you should be able to select it and make the rest of the connections.
Also, the Image files should be "promoted" so they can take input at runtime.
